# Spark compression network and bottleneck

Tags: scala, apache-spark, optimization, compression

I'm working on an ETL based on csv describing file systems to transform it into parquet so I can work on them easily to extract informations.
I'm using [Mr. Powers framework Daria](https://github.com/mrpowers/spark-daria) to do so. I've quiet different input and a lot of transformation and the framework helps organize the code.
I have a stand-alone cluster v2.3.2 composed of 4 node with 8 cores and 32GB of memory each.
The storage is handle by a CephFS volume mounted on all nodes.

First a small description of my algorithm (it's quiet simple):

```
Use SparkContext to load the csv.bz2 file,  
Chain a lot of withColumn() statement,  
Drop all unnecessary columns,
Write parquet file to CephFS
```

This treatment can take several hours depending on how much lines the CSV is and I wanted to identify if bz2 or network could be an issue so I run the following test (several time with consistent result) :

I tried the following scenario with 20 cores and 2 core per task:

- Read the `csv.bz2` from CephFS with connection with 1Gb/s for each node: ~5 minutes.
- Read the `csv.bz2` from TMPFS(setup to look like a shared storage space): ~5 minutes.
- From the 2 previous tests I concluded that uncompressing the file was part of the bottleneck so I decided to uncompress the file and store it in TMPFS as well, result: ~5.9 minutes.

The test file has 25'833'369 lines and is 370MB compressed and 3700MB uncompressed. 
Those results have been reproduced several time each.

My question here is by what am I bottleneck in this case ?  I though that the uncompressed file in RAM would be the fastest.
Is it possible that my program is suboptimal reading the CSV ? in the execution logs on the cluster I have 5 to 10 seconds GC time max, and timeline shows mainly CPU time (no shuffling, no randomization overload either).
I also noticed that memory storage is never used during the execution.

I know from several hours of research that bz2 is the only real compression algorithm usable as an input in spark for parallelization reasons.

**Edit**

In this case the bottleneck came from my VM which were all on the same hypervisor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to identify performance bottle neck, the places you could check are **CPU**, **Disk I/O**, **network bandwidth**, and **memory**. In your case, it seems network and memory could be excluded.

I would suggest you to use some system monitoring software, such **dstat**, to monitor the metrics of the four factors above on each node.

If your CPU usage is close to 100% for **all node**, then it is probably just your algorithm and you probably want to check if you could optimize it.

If CPU usage is low, then I would check the I/O capacity of your file system. Your test that uncompressed data runs slower is likely due to higher I/O cost. Actually, most people compress data for performance: the decompression cost is mostly lower than I/O cost.

If you see unbalanced resource usage across your nodes, the you data could be skewed. Although each node has access to the shared storage, the data still has locality. You might see certain node working longer than its peers or excessive network movement(if data is well distributed, you might see very little network movement).

Comment: I'm going to watch the CPU part closely, because IO on memory is indeed probably not my bottleneck in this case. and I start to think that my algorithm is not that good.

Comment: If that is the case, you can look for even snappy, lzo compression where compression and decompression will be faster which indeed save CPU time in processing.

Comment: @generous_ajay nope if you wan't process lzo or snappy in // with hadoop or spark the only standard implementation available is in bz2.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to processing of large compressed file in Spark, we need to consider factors  of compressed file such as, compressed file size in bytes, compression ratio, decompression time, memory requirements on compression and memory requirements on decompression.

**File Size in bytes and Compression ratio -**

> Let's take a look on bz2 compressed file processing in spark, its ideal for processing in spark as file is split-able automatically, other advantage in terms of compression ratio is high compared to other compressions except gzip and lzma.
>
> But problem with gzip when processing with spark main concern is its not split-able which will degrade processing time in spark. So compression wise bz2 is ideal for spark processing as it has very high compression ratio.
>
> Where if we consider lzma compression its also better option compare to bz2 and split-able also. But only problem is with compression time is higher.

**Decompression time -**

> when it comes to decompression time lzma, it has very fast decompression speed compared to bz2. While others are slower compared to these two.

**Memory requirements for compression and decompression -**

> where if we compare the memory requirement for compression and decompression for bz4, its less compared to other compression format except gzip.

You can find bench marking information different compression format on below link,

https://catchchallenger.first-world.info/wiki/Quick_Benchmark:_Gzip_vs_Bzip2_vs_LZMA_vs_XZ_vs_LZ4_vs_LZO

From above analysis, which one is best compression to it depends on user need if he/she is ready to compromise on processing time and looking for high compression then it he/she can check for higher compression format.

While if user can compromise on storage/memory space and want more processing through put he/she can go for format where compression and decompression is faster.

> But on my opinion about storage/memory space is not an issue when you work on distributed system like spark. Processing through put is more important factor user are more focused and less worried about storage/memory space. Also whenever in spark try to process compressed file it will try to un-compress it first and then process it and if decompression is take more time that would be performance.

Comment: the only splitable implementation in hadoop and spark libraries is bz2. if you want to input compressed file and and process them in parallel fashion, it only really is possible with bz2 though there's better compression algorithm specially lz4 or zstd

Comment: bz2 is good split-able compression in hadoop, but may not agree its the only one compression implementation which is split-able if you can check this even on cloudera link its split-able, https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/categories/hub_lzo.html

Comment: I prefer not to rely on external implementation, I try not to add too much stuff in the basic library. I don't want to deploy an external jar that is not guaranteed to be availablein the future.

Comment: Its up to you, how you want to leverage available resources in you work? my point is, bz2 is not only the option.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the input in a single big single file is usually no a good idea especially if it's archived. The first step of the computation is always loading it and unzipping which is sequential. Then you could leverage parallelism for deserialized data but at a cost of network traffic (which not always pays off).

I suggest splitting the input file into chunks so Spark could read them in parallel.

Comment: This really depends on the file system. For example, if you use HDFS, the file is composed of blocks and read by blocks. A single file would not degrade the performance.

Comment: bz2 can be processed in a parallel manner by spark and many other tools. I can confirm after testing that using S3 CephFS or HDFS is almost the same performance (HDFS is indeed faster at the a heavy cost of local storage and having to maintains yet another file storage system)

Comment: @FangZhang if you e.g. read a file by lines how do you guarantee that each line resides on one block?

Comment: @simpadjo There will be many lines in each block. Say, you have 1 file of size 128 * 100 MB and it is stored as 100 blocks. From outside, you see only 1 file, but internally it is organized by 100 blocks. When spark reads the file, different partition will read different blocks, so that the reading is basically parallel.

Comment: @FangZhang could you please explain how does preserve lines? If the file has a line "abc123\n" is there a guaranty that it will not be broken into "abc" and "123"?

Comment: @simpadjo They don't have to be in the same block, as long as there is a protocol that specifies where to find the next piece of information at the end of the block. A similar example is for traditional database: data are saved in pages, mostly 4KB each; we often have strings longer than that. In that case, we would have to save part of the string in one page, while the rest in other pages. At the end of each partial string, there will be a pointer showing the address of the next piece of the string.

Comment: @FangZhang thank you, will have to learn more about it. Still a bit counterintuitive to me